# Python xml-parsing

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <gameList>
      <game>
        <desc>In the year 2020, baseball finally evolved. There is no longer conventional professional baseball in 2020.</desc>
       </game>
      <game>
        <desc>3 Count Bout is a one-on-one fighting game.</desc>
        </game>

    </gameList>
```

i have a problem when i translate an xml tag with googletrans, only one tag is translated and written on all new tags of the new xml

```
> from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('gamelist.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for game in root.findall('game'):
     desc = game.find('desc').text
     translated = translator.translate(desc, dest='it')

for desc in root.iter('desc'):
     new_desc = (translated.text)
     desc.text = (new_desc)
     tree.write('gamelist1.xml')
```

when I run the code, only the last translated tag is written to the XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have multiple for loops, or really what you're trying to do. My guess is that you want to translate the descriptions to Italian. I think something like this might work:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

translator = Translator()
tree = ET.parse('gamelist.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for game in root.findall('game'):
     desc = game.find('desc')
     translated = translator.translate(desc.text, dest='it').text
     desc.text = translated

tree.write('gamelist1.xml')
```

Comment: I tried the code but by mistake, I should actually translate the descriptions of the XML into Italian. TypeError: cannot serialize <googletrans.models.Translated object at 0x0000021BBE55E190> (type Translated)

Comment: Edited to use the `.text` attribute of the the `Translator` object.

Comment: perfect, now the tags are translated, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Please mark the question as solved if you're happy with the answer.